# How to remap Logitech G510 Multimedia buttons while Media Player Classic is active to seek the video back and forth?

Tags: windows-7, button-remapping, logitech-keyboard

How could I remap some keys to do something similiar as they are mapped to, but only when some of processes is running ? (in my case it's `mpc.exe`).

Here is a pic what I'am trying to explain:

[image]

Actually, when u press **BACKWARD** button, it goes to the previous file, but I need to move it just -5 sec backward on the same video file. Opposite for **FORWARD** button, move +5 sec forward on the same video file.

Did someone something similiar already ?

Or at least, in case of no response, can someone give me a correct navigation where I can find out more about my question ?

Thanks

**==== UPDATED ====**

So after some research, I found out that there are list of available Key commands in MPC's Options > Keys that you could remap, but after some couple tries it didn't worked as I wanted it to.

The whole idea was to watch a video tutorial in MPC on secondary (extended) monitor, while working on primary screen with Active Windows and do not bother to switch the windows to make SEEK BACKWARD and SEEK FORWARD buttons work.

If I will find something, I will sure update the question.

Comment: I dont know of a way to remap the media keys. Why not just remap one of the 18 other remappable keys on the left though?

Comment: I was thinking about that as a plan B... Any clue how to code it ? I'am noob in that :(

Comment: It has to do with `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\AppKey`. See this sample chapter from [Windows XP Registry Guide](http://www.microsoft.com/mspress/books/sampchap/6232.aspx#120)

Comment: It looks like the ==== UPDATED ==== section of your question got cut off -- please correct for the benefit of others.

Comment: still cut off @aspirinemaga

Comment: Sorry guys, but it doesn't work as I wanted it to. I will clear the question